# How to highlight words from one file in another file? (Linux)

Tags: linux, bash, vim, grep, do-while

```
host hostname {
        hardware ethernet 00:10:E0:dF:e2:Ee;
        fixed-address 192.168.*.*;
ddns-hostname name;
}
```

I have list of ip addresses in one file. How can I highlight those addresses in dhcpd.hosts file and still to see the whole block or the whole text?
emphasized text
I've tried to use while read variable; do grep $variable dhcpd.hosts; done < iplistfile

but it's printing only one line

Comment: Couldn't you find a vim plugin for this? There must be one

Comment: I suppose it's there but I couldn't find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want

```sh
grep --color=always -f iplistfile dhcpd.hosts
```

and you might want to add the `-F` and `-w` options too.